# Adding None option to ModelChoiceFilter

Tags: django-filter

My filter has been working great but I'd like the option to select None to find Transactions where merchant_group==None. I can't find this option in the docs, is it not possible?

```
class TransactionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    merchant_group = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name='merchant__merchant_group', empty_label="Merchant", queryset=MerchantGroup.objects.all().order_by('name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

[ModelChoiceFilter extends ChoiceFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=choicefilter#choicefilter) and passing a `null_value` (and a `null_label` optionally) can help you achieve this. Your code would look something like:

```py
class TransactionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    merchant_group = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        field_name='merchant__merchant_group', empty_label="Merchant", queryset=MerchantGroup.objects.all().order_by('name'), null_value=None, null_label='No merchant group'
    )
```